# ffmpeg stopped when set "-i" option with rtsp URL

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04, vlc-media-player, rtsp

I am using ffmpeg on Ubuntu 12.4 to get thumbnails from RTSP URL.

I confirmed with vlc that this URL is fine,

Video file played nicely.

The problem is ffmpeg.

I command like

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset -4 -i "rtsp://cug.fostv.com:554/test/smarttv_sample.ts.pac" -vframes 1 -an -s 320x240 /home/guest/sample.bmp
```

it shows message below and just stopped.

Is there any way to prove what's wrong with my system?

It could be VMware NAT problem or ffmpeg's own.

Give me some hints.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/guest/Downloads# ffmpeg -itsoffset -4 -i "rtsp://cug.fostv.com:554/test/smarttv_sample.ts.pac" -vframes 1 -an -s 320x240 /home/guest/sample.bmp
ffmpeg version git-2013-05-29-a58e10e Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 29 2013 11:05:12 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      52. 34.100 / 52. 34.100
  libavcodec     55. 12.101 / 55. 12.101
  libavformat    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavdevice    55.  1.101 / 55.  1.101
  libavfilter     3. 72.100 /  3. 72.100
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[rtsp @ 0x332d880] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this:D

It needs some additional options.

My command was like below.

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset -4 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://cug.fostv.com:554/test/smarttv_sample.ts.pac -vframes 1 -s 420x270 /home/guest/ffmpegsample.bmp
```

anyways, the output image quality is totally disaster:(